# Are there benefits to checking for segue identifiers rather than using failed type casting?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue

When we implement a `prepareForSegue:sender:` method in a `UIViewController` subclass that has multiple segues, one idiom in Objective-C is to assign an identifier to the segue in the storyboard, and wrap the logic in `prepareForSegue:sender:` in an `if` statement that inspects the segue `identifier`. For example:

```
if segue.identifier == "destinationA"
    // prepare destinationA stuff
else if segue.identifier == "destinationB"
    // prepare destinationB stuff
...
```

In Swift, we're essentially forced by the API to use type casting when obtaining the instance of the destination view controller. Since this can fail gracefully, **my question is** should we go ahead and rely on optional binding with conditional type casting (`as?`) or should we still rely on an `if` statement?

For example, where possible, should we favor the succinctness of relying on just type casting:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? DestinationAController {
        // prepare stuff for Destination A
    } else if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? DestinationBController {
        // prepare stuff for Destination B
    }
}
```

Or is there a benefit in still wrapping everything in an `if` statement like we did in Objective-C:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "destinationA" {
        if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? DestinationAController {
            // prepare stuff for Destination A
        }
    } else if segue.identifier == "destinationB" {
        if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? DestinationBController {
            // prepare stuff for Destination B
        }   
    }
}
```

*Note: I realize a switch can be used, but that's not the point here.*

Comment: I suppose one scenario I can think of is where you have different segues that transition to different instances of the same controller type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relying on the identifier has the benefit that if your source/destination view controller got changed to another class, you can catch it more easily because it will fall into the right identifier bucket but fail the downcast. Strictly speaking, the code path is not the same.  With the more succinct style, the failed case won't be caught until after all downcasts have been performed.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "destinationA" {
        if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? DestinationAController {
            // prepare stuff for Destination A
        }
        else {
           print("Something is wrong with the controller for destination A!")
        }
    } else if segue.identifier == "destinationB" {
        if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? DestinationBController {
            // prepare stuff for Destination B
        }   
    }
}
```

vs.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? DestinationAController {
        // prepare stuff for Destination A
    } else if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? DestinationBController {
        // prepare stuff for Destination B
    }
    else {
      print("Something is wrong with the controller!")
    }
}
```

Another benefit is that you can do some other logic after the identifier test and before performing the downcast.

It's also quicker to read the code using identifier in terms of intent - not only is it shorter, identifier being a Swift string can be made quite descriptive.